# My website on a remote server won't display

Tags: php, web, server

[image]

How can I display my site properly? I'm using a remote linux server and pulling the files from GitLab. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You dont appear to have an `index.html` or `index.php` that is the only file that will run automatically in a normal web server. It shoudl be your homepage or launch your homepage

Comment: You'd normally click on `README.md` to see if there're instructions to set your web server. But it's a 16 byte file so I suspect you're out of luck. My guess is that `homepage.php` is meant to be the entry point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `index.php` or `index.html` file, so your server displays default directory listing view (this is security issue)